# Html.RenderAction in Razor doesn't work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, rendering

I want to use RenderAction, but I'm getting an error:

> Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper'.

My view:

```
@{
    Layout = string.Empty;
}

@{ Html.RenderAction("AssetStructureChart"); }
```

Controler:

```
public ContentResult AssetStructureChart() {
  return Content("test");
}
```

And I don't use any layout. I don't understand why this doesn't work. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implemented this through c# extension methods.

```
public static MvcHtmlString AssetStructureChart(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper)
{
   return MvcHtmlString.Create("test");
}
```

And in view:

```
@Html.AssetStructureChart(false)
```